# How to notify Facebook of no consent to their use of my information?

Tags: united-states, privacy, data-protection, consent

I do not have a Facebook account (and never had one under any alias). I'd like to notify Facebook that I do not consent to their storing / displaying any information related to me (images of me, name and / or any other information that relates to me), even if uploaded by someone else (including services that may upload information about me through their use of Facebook for tracking, etc.)

If it makes a difference, I have dual citizenship in the US and in the EU. I live in the US.

Is this legally doable and if yes, how would I do it?

(In case I didn't phrase my question right, the intent of the question is whether I can force Facebook with such a notice to remove / stop future recording any information related to me, regardless of its source.)

Comment: How would they know it's a picture of you? How do they know the "information relates to you"? Just because it may be a picture of you, doesn't automatically mean you own the rights to it or can govern its use...

Comment: @RonBeyer that is part of why I'm asking the question and it's not something I considered.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted - I looked through existing questions on the site and didn't find a duplicate and otherwise I believe I formed the question in a clear-enough way to be answerable. It may be a misguided question but in that case an answer can easily point that out.

Comment: If you are physically present in the EU, then the GDPR would seem to apply, and that would give you some rights in the matter. If you are not, it would not apply. Are you physically present in any EU country now? Citizenship does not matter for this. If you are resident in California, similar rights under the CCPA would apply. Are you?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I live in the US - I'll update the question with that detail.

Comment: Privacy law in the US is generally state law, not federal law, so you should specify which state you're in.

Answer (score 1):

The reported mail address is Facebook Headquarters, 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA 94025, so you could write your claim in a letter and mail it to them. However, they do not necessarily have to care whether you consent to them using information about you. For example, imagine that they use your name and image in advertising. That would require your consent under California law, so you could sue them for violating your right of personality. In that case, the letter might threaten to sue them if they don't pay you or cease using your personal "information" (you can write a letter, or you can hire a lawyer). You are not required to threaten them, so you could just file a lawsuit, but traditionally people send such letters because actually suing a company like Facebook is complicated and potentially expensive. In general, unless the information is highly personal and its publication is objectively offensive, and is not infringement of copyright, your consent is not required in the US.

Your citizenship is irrelevant, what matters is where you are. If FB "processed" your personal data when you were in an EU state and did not get your consent, they could have run afoul of GDPR. Your letter could then outline the facts and your demands (such as taking a picture down).